# Spring 3.0 MVC custom WebArgumentResolver skips validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

We've got a couple of `@RequestMapping` annotated controllers methods that do stuff. They each have more than 1 argument that we would like to be bound. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a/b", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response getAB(ARequest aRequest, BRequest bRequest) throws ServiceException {
    ...
}
```

This obviously works fine. However, one quirk in our requirements is that we get request parameters that contain *underscores*. For example; on the endpoint above we'd get a request that looks like: `http://x:8000/a/b?req_param=1`. This causes default Spring binding to fail, because in our objects we'd like to have bound we define `req_param` camel-cased (`reqParam`) rather than use underscores in our Java code.

To solve this we have implemented our own annotation (`@Camelize`) and our own custom `WebArgumentResolver`, which we've registered in the Spring context. We then annotate our controller method arguments with `@Camelize`, which causes our custom `WebArgumentResolver` to step in and correct the binding. This also works fine.

Now the issues arise, more specifically it would appear that when we want to also *validate* our arguments this fails. For example, continuing with the example above:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a/b", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response getAB(@Camelize @Valid ARequest aRequest, Errors aRequestErrors, BRequest bRequest) throws ServiceException {
    ...
}
```

This fails with the exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!`.

It would appear that we cannot use our custom `WebArgumentResolver` and validate using `@Valid` at the same time. We have narrowed it down to the custom `WebArgumentResolver`, in the sense that *as soon as* this *doesn't* return `UNRESOLVED`, Spring MVC will just not bother with validation and throw the exception above.

- Can anyone confirm that this is the expected behaviour?
- Is there a work-around for this? Currently we're thinking about removing the custom `WebArgumentResolver` and replacing it with a filter, but this seems very intrusive for what we need.

Thanks!

**Edit:** we're using Spring 3.0.5.

Comment: I suppose you can not use Errors as argument in this case. See if [this link](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6709) helps

Comment: @vinay Good link. It would appear that this issue is indeed related to the `BindingResult` argument(s). There's an interesting "workaround" in the comments there as well. Worth a try.